# How can I make my seeds correctly working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm still new in Ruby / Rails and I need your help to be sure my seed is good before running my command `rails db:seed`

Here my seed:

```
require 'faker'

puts "Creating 10 fake user heros..."
10.times do
  user = User.create!(
    username: Faker::DcComics.hero,
    password: "123456",
    email: "#{user.username}@gmail.com",
    bio: "Hi, I'm #{user.username}. Faker::Movie.quote",
    avatar: Faker::LoremFlickr.image(size: "900x900", search_terms: ['dccomics'])
  )
  puts "#{user.username} created!"
end

puts "Creating 10 fake hero services..."
10.times do
  service = Service.create!(
    name: "#{Faker::Verb.ing_form} service",
    description: "I'll use my #{Faker::Superhero.power} to accomplish the mission",
    address: "#{Faker::Address.street_address}, #{Faker::Address.city}",
    photos: Faker::LoremFlickr.image(size: "900x900", search_terms: ["#{Faker::Verb.ing_form}"]),
    user_id: rand(user.id)
  )
  puts "#{service.name} created!"
end

puts "Finished!"
```

I think I'll have several issues especially:

- My interpolation : I'm not sure I'm allowed to use it with Faker
- I'd like to use the same username given in `username` and `email`, am I doing right?
- My user model doesn't have an avatar in the DB table but `has_one_attached :avatar`, may I give it a seed?
- Related question about my service model (`has_many_attached :photos`). How can I generate several pictures for it?
- I'd like to give a random `user_id` from one of those created above to my service model, I don't really know how could I proceed...

Comment: You have development and testing databases which can be deleted and recreated if something goes wrong. Try it!

Comment: Hi Schwern, I did! I tried to launch my seeds but I got the ```rails aborted```message and I can't figure out why

Comment: `rails aborted` comes with an error message with a big stack trace of what methods were called to get to the error. There's a lot of stuff from inside Rails. Ignore that. Look at the parts which are in your code like `db/seed.rb` or `app/models/user.rb` and ignore the rest. It's probably ```undefined method `username' for nil:NilClass```.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My interpolation : I'm not sure I'm allowed to use it with Faker

Interpolation works with any expression. Even multiple statements. `"#{ a = 1 + 1; b = 2 + 2; a + b}"` will produce `"6"`. But don't do that, it's confusing.

```
name: "#{Faker::Verb.ing_form} service",
```

is equivalent to

```
name: Faker::Verb.ing_form.to_s + " service"
```

In a few places you're missing the interpolation.

```
bio = "Hi, I'm #{user.username}. Faker::Movie.quote"
```

That should be...

```
bio = "Hi, I'm #{user.username}. #{Faker::Movie.quote}"
```

In other places the interpolation is not necessary.

```
search_terms: ["#{Faker::Verb.ing_form}"]
```

`Faker::Verb.ing_form` already returns a string and does not need to be interpolated.

```
search_terms: [Faker::Verb.ing_form]
```

---

> I'd like to use the same username given in username and email, am I doing right?

No, you can't reference `user` until it's already been created. If you try you will get something like `` undefined method `username' for nil:NilClass ``. `user` is `nil` and `nil` doesn't have a method called `username`.

Instead you could make a user, set its email, then save.

```
user = User.new(
  username: Faker::DcComics.hero,
  password: "123456",
  avatar: Faker::LoremFlickr.image(size: "900x900", search_terms: ['dccomics'])
)
user.email = "#{user.username}@gmail.com"
user.bio = "Hi, I'm #{user.username}. #{Faker::Movie.quote}"
user.save!
```

Or you can make the username first and store it in a variable to reference.

```
  username = Faker::DcComics.hero
  user = User.create!(
    username: username,
    password: "123456",
    email: "#{username}@gmail.com",
    bio: "Hi, I'm #{username}. #{Faker::Movie.quote}",
    avatar: Faker::LoremFlickr.image(size: "900x900", search_terms: ['dccomics'])
  )
```

---

> My user model doesn't have an avatar in the DB table but has_one_attached :avatar, may I give it a seed?

I'm not super familiar with [attachments in Rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#attaching-files-to-records), but I think it should work as you've written.

---

> I'd like to give a random user_id from one of those created above to my service model, I don't really know how could I proceed...

The simple thing is to use [`sample`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Array.html#method-i-sample).

```
user = User.all.sample
```

We can make this a little better using `pluck` to fetch just the ID.

```
user = User.pluck(:id).sample
```

However, this loads all Users. For a small test database that's not a problem. For production code that's a huge waste. Instead we can use `order by random() limit 1`. In Rails 6 it's kinda clunky.

```
User.order(Arel.sql('RANDOM()')).pluck(:id).first
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25577054/14660) for an explanation.

And note, if you already have a User loaded, pass the User, not its ID. This avoids Service having to load the User again.

```
10.times do
  user = User.order(Arel.sql('RANDOM()')).pluck(:id).first
  service = Service.create!(
    ...
    user: user
  )
end
```

But there's a better way...

---

> Related question about my service model (has_many_attached :photos). How can I generate several pictures for it?

And here we reach the real leap. Instead of generating static test data, use a Factory. [FactoryBot](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md) makes it easy to define "factories" to generate test data using Faker. You're already halfway there. And [FactoryBotRails](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot_rails) lets FactoryBot understand how to Rails models.

A User factory would look like this.

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    username { Faker::DcComics.hero }
    password { "123456" }
    email { "#{username}@gmail.com" }
    bio { "Hi, I'm #{username}. #{Faker::Movie.quote}" }
    avatar { Faker::LoremFlickr.image(size: "900x900", search_terms: ['dccomics']) }
  end
end
```

Note that we *can* make an `email` based on the `username`. Attributes can reference other attributes. That's because the attributes are actually little functions kinda like this:

```
class UserFactory do
  def username
    @username ||= Faker::DDcComics.hero
  end

  def email
    @email ||= "#{username}@gmail.com"
  end
end
```

And to make 10 of them...

```
users = FactoryBot.create_list(:user, 10)
```

You can override the defaults. If you want a user with a certain email address...

```
user = FactoryBot.create(:user, email: "c.kent@dailyplanet.com")
```

Since you can make users on the fly, you no longer need to seed specific data.

Now Service. Let's look at the Service factory. To make a Service we need Photos.

```
  factory :service do
    name { "#{Faker::Verb.ing_form} service" }
    description { "I'll use my #{Faker::Superhero.power} to accomplish the mission" }
    address { "#{Faker::Address.street_address}, #{Faker::Address.city}" }
    user
    # photos is presumably has-many_attached and so takes an Array.
    photos {
      [
       Faker::LoremFlickr.image(
         size: "900x900",
         search_terms: [Faker::Verb.ing_form]
       )
      ]
    }
  end
```

Have a look at `user`. FactoryBot will automatically fill that in with a User made using your User factory. The problem of making a Service with a random User is solved.

Our final step is to [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) up our factories by defining one to make a photo.

```
factory :photo, class: Faker::LoremFlickr do
  size { "900x900" }
  search_terms { Faker::Lorem.words }

  initialize_with do
    Faker::LoremFlickr.image(attributes)
  end
end
```

This is not a Rails model, so we need to teach FactoryBot how to make a photo by providing it with its class and [how to initialize it](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#custom-construction). `attributes` is a Hash containing size and search_terms.

Also note that I used more generic search terms. Factories which need specific search terms will provide their own.

We can make as many photos as we want.

```
photos = FactoryBot.build_list(:photos, 3)
```

Using the Photo factory we can DRY up the User and Service factories. Here it is all together.

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :photo, class: Faker::LoremFlickr do
    size { "900x900" }
    search_terms { Faker::Lorem.words }

    initialize_with do
      Faker::LoremFlickr.image(attributes)
    end
  end

  factory :user do
    username { Faker::DcComics.hero }
    password { "123456" }
    email { "#{username}@gmail.com" }
    bio { "Hi, I'm #{username}. #{Faker::Movie.quote}" }
    avatar { build(:photo, search_terms: ['dccomics']) }
  end

  factory :service do
    name { "#{Faker::Verb.ing_form} service" }
    description { "I'll use my #{Faker::Superhero.power} to accomplish the mission" }
    address { "#{Faker::Address.street_address}, #{Faker::Address.city}" }
    user
    photos {
      build_list(:photo, 3, search_terms: [Faker::Verb.ing_form])
    }
  end
end
```

And now, when you need a service to test with, you can ask for one.

```
service = FactoryBot.create(:service)
```

Want a service with a different name?

```
service = FactoryBot.create(:service, name: "Universal Exports")
```

What about with no photos?

```
service = FactoryBot.create(:service, photos: [])
```

That's just scratching the surface of what FactoryBot can do.

Factories are far more flexible and convenient than seed files.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks for all the explanations, it's really helpful and super interesting, I learned a lot! I'll try to use ```factory``` in my app, it really seems to be simpler, thanks again Schwern!

Comment: Nitpicking, but the attributes work more like `def username ; @username ||= Faker::DDcComics.hero ; end`, i.e. they _memoize_ their value so you can reuse it across the factory.

Answer (score 0):

In the `aborted` message there must be a specific line where seeds is failing. Possibly, it can be the `email`. What if a username is: "The Joker"? Email can not be "The Joker@gmail.com@".

Try this:

```
require 'faker'

puts "Creating 10 fake user heros..."
10.times do
  user = User.create!(
    username: Faker::DcComics.hero,
    password: "123456",
    email: "#{username..gsub(/\s+/, "").downcase}@gmail.com",
    bio: "Hi, I'm #{user.username}. #{Faker::Movie.quote}"
  )
  puts "#{user.username} created!"
end
```

Comment: Thx for your answer Yshmarov, you were right, it comes first from the ```email``` I tried your code but I still have an error message : ```NameError: undefined local variable or method `username' for main:Object```.

Btw, why are you using ```split```? Is it not better to use this : ```"The Joker".gsub(/\s+/, "").downcase```?

Comment: `split` is just an example of how you can modify the username.

Comment: Actually your `gsub` approach is very good. `"The Joker".gsub(/\s+/, "").downcase  => "thejoker"`

Comment: Ok makes sense. Thanks for your help!